# How to remove part of URL with htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have a lot of pages with `%20` in them, I can't rename them.

So I've got `https://mywebsite.com/WEB/111%20111%201111/` and I want to make that `https://mywebsite.com/WEB/1111111111/`.

I simply want to remove `%20` via .htaccess.

I can't find a way online.

Comment: The %20 looks like it's an url encoded space character. I'm not sure if `111%20111%201111` is a generated file or something. But maybe it would be an option to remove the spaces. In case of .htaccess, I guess you would need a pretty specific rule so no other things get broken. For example if you have a filter somewhere and parameters are being url encoded.

Comment: I have more than 140 pages with %20 in them because I am trying to renew an old website, and I can't remove it directly from the name as the owner said not to. So I'm trying to remove them with htaccess, but idk if there is a better method.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44733073/how-to-remove-20-from-url-with-htaccess) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519154/htaccess-rewrite-replace-space-with) can help you. But as far as I can see, the rules mentioned there will replace more than just `%20`. So maybe you have to modify the rule